# Select2 adds a title attribute to form controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 version 3.4.8 and have recently noticed that the code is adding a `title` attribute to each form control in my page, using the text of the associate `label` for the `title`. I assume the Select2 developers meant this as an accessibility improvement, but it is a dubious choice, as there already is an associated `label`.

I am looking for a way to disable this without patching `select2.js` directly. I've looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything. Is there a way to do this, or do I either have to patch `select2.js` (perhaps commenting out line 692) or write a few lines of script to remove `title` attributes after they've been added to `.select2-container` divs? (Or is this fixed in version 3.5.0?)

Comment: The `title` attribute is indeed useless in that case. Why not submit a pull request to the [github project](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2)?

Comment: Wouldn't submitting a pull request mean I have to make the actual code changes myself? For my current use, I've simply commented out the offending line, but I don't know the code base well enough to know what kind of knock-on changes that might have on other functionality that I don't use. Anyway, the question is, "Is there an option for disabling this without changing the actual select2 code?"

Comment: Opening an issue is just writing some text. A Pull Request needs to change some code, true

Answer (score 1):

When loading the page add the following script:

> $(".select2-selection__rendered").removeAttr('title');

This will remove the title.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute here is useless, but also harmless. It gets applied to an offscreen version of the element that has `tabindex="-1"`. An element with `tabindex="-1"` cannot receive keyboard focus by default, and this will never be announced by assistive tech (unless explicitly given focus with javascript).

Only the associated label will be announced. I've verified this behavior with VoiceOver/Chrome.

Comment: Well, it's not harmless, aesthetically. Or when my boss comes round asking why I've added a tooltip to a control. ;)

Comment: I'm surprised it adds a tooltip, since the `title` attribute is on an element that is not on the screen. Have you experienced the behavior yourself?

Comment: Yeah, it's adding the `title` attribute to the `.select2-container`, which is on-screen, instead of to the label, which is off-screen.